# Prove $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\, \mathrm{d}x = e + \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\pi^2 + \ln^2 x}\, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, gamma-function

I came across this nice identity:
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\, \mathrm{d}x = e + \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\pi^2 + \ln^2 x}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

Is there an elementary proof?

Comment: $\pi,\Gamma,e,\ln,\infty,0$ together. I am not sure if this is elegant or an abomination.

Comment: This is the [Fransen-Robinson constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fransen-Robinson_constant), the continuous equivalent of *e*, and whose approximate value is about $2.708880^+$.

Comment: IMHO, in a whole year I joined MSE, this is probably the most beautiful identity I have seen.

Comment: @Lucian (+1 for the link), what do you mean "continuous equivalent" of $e$ , are you referring to $$e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}?$$

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar First, in your $u$-sub, it should be $$\int_{-1}^\infty \frac1{u}\,{\rm d}u$$ and second, to *integrate* you need a continuous function, so back to $\Gamma$.

Comment: As far as I know(from the book "Mathmatical Constant" of S.R.Finch, p263-p264), this formula was discovered by Ramanujan. Hardy proved a generalized version of this formula in his paper "Another formula  of Ramanujan", J.London Math.Soc. (1937) s1-12 (4): 314-318.

Comment: @yzhao Why does that surprise me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hardy recorded in his 1937 papers that the formula was discovered by Ramanujan, who did not profess to **prove** such an identity. Hardy published his proof, which was based on the ["Plana's formula"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula)(A proof of Plana's formula can be found [here](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~ums/pdf/abelplana.pdf)). Here is an outline of Hardy's original proof. I doubt whether an "*elementary*" proof exists(without complex analysis).

The Plana's formula asserts that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n)-\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}f(0)+i\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(it)-f(-it)}{e^{2\pi t}-1}dt$$

Let $f(u)=1/\Gamma(u)$, then $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}dx=i\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1/\Gamma(it)-1/\Gamma(-it)}{e^{2\pi t}-1}dt$$

An elementary transform of RHS gives

$$i\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1/\Gamma(it)-1/\Gamma(-it)}{e^{2\pi t}-1}dt=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1/\Gamma(it)}{\sin \pi i t}e^{-\pi\vert t\vert}dt$$

Also $$e^{-\pi\vert t\vert}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{it}}{u(\pi^2+\log^2u)}du$$

Then RHS is equal to $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{it}}{u(\pi^2+\log^2u)}\frac{-1/\Gamma(it)}{2\sin \pi i t}dudt$$

Mellin transform gives $$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{\pi u^{z-1}}{\Gamma(z)\sin \pi z}dz=-e^{-u}$$

where C is the imaginary axis.

And we are done.

Comment: +1. Nice solution. I was trying to use
[Euler Reflection Formula](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler's_Reflection_Formula) but it became a mess !!!.